# xcode 6 ota distribution fails

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I had a small app I wanted a friend to test, he's far away, so back then, I used ota distribution, I followed a step by step explanation and it went good.

I upgraded my app to ios8 among other updates in it, and I want to do the same : put it in my website, I searched for information about this, but all I got was outdated tutorials / informations.

I suppose I did allmost everything correctly :

- created an app id
- had the udid of my friend and some others on apple's website.
- made a distribution (or provisionning or whatever they're called) certificate using this app id and my list of udid.
- downloaded it and put it in my keychain.
- told xcode to sign with it on release
- archived it
- saved it for ad hoc distribution

so there I should only move the .plist .ipa to my site and point my tester to this site, but it doesn't work. First, organizer only outputs a .ipa file when it used to generate a .plist and a .ipa and it used to ask for two images. I read somewhere that xcode 6 only exports a ipa now, so I tried using my newly made ipa and put it on my site along with my old .plist and it failed with the following error message : "the applications can't be installed because [mysite]'s certificate is invalid." (translated from french), that would imply I didn't use the right certificate to sign my release, but I'm quite sure I did.

in conclusion, I'm really lost, and I think I should restart the whole process, so any pointers to an up to date step by step tutorial, or some quick explanation of what I'd be missing / doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just to notice,

Remember your plist should be in an "https" server. If you don´t have an https server with a valid certificate you could upload your plist to a dropbox public link (this works perfect).

Comment: Xcode 6 doesn't provide the plist anymore. It sounds like this is @moo's problem.